# Proper way for memory testing on a server

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, memory, server-crashes

I am a self taught system administrator at a little company. Our DC (which is a windows server 2012 r2 virtual machine running on a ESXi 6.0 host) recently started to crash with a BSOD at random in every 1-4 hour. After analyzing the dump files I got to a point where I assumed it might be caused by bad RAM in the physical server. Now I would like to check it, and I created an Ubuntu 18.04 installation USB, but the server hangs at loading screen before the installation option even would show up. Although I am not sure if the problem really is with the RAM, since all of the other VM'S (which are 2 more Windows servers and one Windows 7 clients) were running just fine, I would ask for a help on how to correctly check the memory on this Fujitsu Primergy rx1330 m2 server.

Any suggestions and tips are appriciated! (if it could help I can send the minidump files as well)

Answer (score 1):

Testing the RAM should be done on the physical hardware, ie. the host, using Memtest86 or something similar.

A host should have ECC ram and management, so you can rule out single-bit errors inside the VMs and when using the management functions (log, SNMP, IPMI, ...) you can check for more severe errors.